# Parse equation to list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples, equation

I want to parse equations and get a list of tuples. 
For example, when I enter

```
2x = 4+3y,
```

I want to get

```
[('', '2', 'x', '='), ('','4','',''), ('+','3','y','')]
```

This is my regex so far:

```
([+-]*)([0-9]+)([a-z]*)([<=>]*)
```

It works fine for the above query but it does not capture equations like

`2 = x +3y`, (where x does not have any coefficient)

How do I capture that?

Comment: Best way to parse an equation in infix notation is [Shunting Yard algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Infix notation isn't a regular language, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d*)(\w*) *(=) *(\d*)(\w*) *[+|\-|*|/] *(\d*)(\w*)
```

How about this regex?

It separates all operands and operators. (and inside operands it also splits number and variable).

*For testing the regex I normally use https://regex101.com/ so you can build regex with live changes there.*

Answer (score 0):

If you change the quantifier on the coefficient from `+` *(one or more)* to `*` *(zero or more)* then you should get the result you are after. You will also get an empty string match due to all the quantifiers now being `*` but you can filter out that match.

```
>>> import re
>>> e1 = "2x=4+3y"
>>> e2 = "2=x+3y"
>>> re.findall("([+-]*)([0-9]*)([a-z]*)([<=>]*)", e1)
[('', '2', 'x', '='), ('', '4', '', ''), ('+', '3', 'y', ''), ('', '', '', '')]
>>> re.findall("([+-]*)([0-9]*)([a-z]*)([<=>]*)", e2)
[('', '2', '', '='), ('', '', 'x', ''), ('+', '3', 'y', ''), ('', '', '', '')]
```

Note: whilst this solves your direct question this is not a good approach to parsing infix equations.

Comment: How do we get rid of ('', '', '', '') ?

Comment: One solution using list comprehensions - `[m for m in match if ''.join(m)]`