# Regular expression to match the linear system ax+by=c

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm looking for the best regular expression to match the linear system with 2 unknowns (ax+by=c) for Python module ’re’. Where a, b and c are positive or negative integers and I need to separate the match in 
3 groups each one contains the value of a, b and c (with signs): group 1 containing ‘a’ value’s, group 2 containing ‘b’ value’s and group 3 containing ‘c’ value’s.

e.g.:

for -3x+y=-2,  group1 will contain -3, group 2 will contain 1 and group 3 will contain -2

e.g.:

```
x+3y=-4
-2x+y=2
3x-y=2
```

...

What I used so far is :

```
r"(^[+-]?\d*)x([+-]?\d*)y=([+-]?\d*)"
```

It almost woks fine except when it has to deal with a negative sign and a or b are missing.
e.g.:

```
-x+2y=4
5x-y=3
```

I have to put 1 before x or y if they're negative to make it work:

```
-x+2y=4 => -1x+2=4
5x-y=3 => 5x-1y=3
```

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import re

def solve(eq1,eq2):
    match1 = re.match(r"(^[+-]?\d*)x([+-]?\d*)y=([+-]?\d*)", eq1)
    a1, b1, c1 = match1.groups()
    if a1 is None or a1== '':
        a1=1
    elif a1 == '-':
        a1=-1       
    if b1 is None:
        b1=1
    elif b1 == '-':
        b1=-1
    elif b1 == '+':
        b1 = 1
    a1, b1, c1 = float(a1), float(b1), float(c1) 
    match2 = re.match(r"([+-]?\d*)x([+-]?\d*)y=([+-]?\d*)", eq2)
    a2, b2, c2 = match2.groups()
    if a2 is None or a2== '':
        a2=1
    elif a2 == '-':
        a2=-1

    if b2 is None:
        b2=1
    elif b2 == '-':
        b2=-1
    elif b2 == '+':
        b2 = 1  
    a2, b2, c2 = float(a2), float(b2), float(c2)    
    A = np.array([[a1, b1], [a2, b2]])
    B = np.array([[c1], [c2]]) 
    print(np.linalg.inv(A) @ B)

solve("x-y=7","2x+3y=4")
```

## Output:

[[ 5.][-2.]]

Comment: How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/ExlTLy/3)?

Comment: Note `y` is missing in `-x+2=4` and if you add it there, [your regex works](https://regex101.com/r/XODOLL/1)

Comment: Note the comment on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840645/parse-equation-to-list-of-tuples-in-python

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just fogot to put the 'y' in the example...

Comment: So, your regex matches all the strings you want, doesn't it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yep but I think that the problem comes from my python code when using 're' module for matching groups...

Comment: Add the code then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, code added. Without the if statments, -x or/and -y won't work but  with -1x or/and -1y it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split based on regular expression `x|y=`, considering empty strings and `+` or `-` without numbers.

```
import re

ee = ['x+3y=-4', '-2x+y=2', '3x-y=2', '-x+2y=4', '5x-y=3']
for e in ee:
    print([int(m+'1' if m in ['', '+', '-'] else m)
          for m in re.split('x|y=', e)])
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3, -4]
[-2, 1, 2]
[3, -1, 2]
[-1, 2, 4]
[5, -1, 3]
```

**Update #1:**

```
import numpy as np
import re

def solve(eq1, eq2):
  coeffs = []
  for e in [eq1, eq2]:
    for m in re.split('x|y=', e):
      coeffs.append(float(m + '1' if m in '+-' else m))
  a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2 = coeffs
  A = np.array([[a1, b1], [a2, b2]])
  B = np.array([[c1], [c2]])
  return np.linalg.inv(A) @ B

print(solve("x-y=7", "2x+3y=4"))
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 5.]
 [-2.]]
```

Check it online with [rextester](https://rextester.com/GBW12531).

Comment: I need to use nupy module to solve the matrix equation for ax+by=c and dx+ey=f

Comment: @avode thanks for your answer concerning the python code using numpy module.